# Firebird 4 - Shared memory area is probably already created by another engine instance in another Windows session

Tags: windows, firebird

We use Firebird and are looking to move from FB 2.5 to FB 4.0.2.2816 and have run into an odd problem doing database restores.

When we restore a database using the following command in command prompt

`gbak.exe -c -o -v -user {ProgramAdmin} -password {Password} -page_size 8192 "C:\MyFolder\fb4.fbk" "C:\MyFolder\Restore.fdb"`

We get the error message

```
gbak:opened file C:\MyFolder\fb4.fbk 
gbak:transportable backup -- data in XDR format
gbak:       backup file is compressed
gbak:backup version is 11
gbak: ERROR:Shared memory area is probably already created by another engine instance in another Windows session
gbak: ERROR:failed to create database C:\MyFolder\Restore.fdb
gbak:Exiting before completion due to errors
```

The Windows 10 user we run this as is a limited domain user (not an admin) with this message appearing ~90% of the time, with the other 10% been ok and the database restoring as expected.

No other firebird instances are running, and no other user is logged into the computer.

If we run command prompt as a local admin, the error appears to go away.

So I am not sure if this is a user access problem or a network access problem.  Backing up the database as the limited user works 100% of the time.

The {ProgramAdmin} user is set as RDB:ADMIN but is not SYSDBA, we have tried it with SYSDBA and without a username / password in the parameters and that still raised the error.

This worked fine in Firebird 2.5 so it looks to be a FB 4 thing.

Has anyone encountered this before or have any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between Firebird 2.5 and Firebird 3.0 and higher is that - on Windows - if you didn't specify a server, Firebird 2.5 would connect to the local server with XNET, while Firebird 3.0 and higher use the embedded engine by default.

As far as I'm aware, that is what is causing the error here if your Firebird server is running as a service (IIRC, there is a bug fix that will prevent this error in the next version). To avoid this error, you will need to make sure you connect through the server instead of using the embedded engine.

To do that, replace `"C:\MyFolder\Restore.fdb"` with `"xnet://C:\MyFolder\Restore.fdb"` (uses XNET) or `"localhost:C:\MyFolder\Restore.fdb"` or `"inet://localhost/C:\MyFolder\Restore.fdb"` (both use TCP/IP). For example:

`gbak.exe -c -o -v -user {ProgramAdmin} -password {Password} -page_size 8192 "C:\MyFolder\fb4.fbk" "xnet://C:\MyFolder\Restore.fdb"`

Comment: Thanks adding xnet:// solved the problem, I didnt know they used the embedded  connection without that.

Comment: @Re0sless This is described in the Firebird 3.0 Release Notes (specifically [here](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#_the_components), but it might be worthwhile to study the entire thing). I will see if maybe I need to make some changes to the gfix documentation to highlight this.

Comment: I meant the gbak documentation...